# A problem on prime numbers from IYMC

Tags: number-theory

This problem is from the pre-final round for the 2018 year of the competition
IYMC.

> Find a function $θ(n)$ with following behaviour:
>   $$θ(n) = \begin{cases}
> 0 \text{ if } n \text{ is composed} \\
> n \text{ if } n \text{ is prime}
> \end{cases}
> $$

Comment: That is a function.

Comment: For what it's worth, the OP is asking about problem C.2 at https://iymc.info/docs/problems/2018/Pre-Final-Round-Problems-2018.pdf -- sandwiched between two rather more difficult problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\theta(n)=n(\pi(n)-\pi(n-1))$$

Answer (score 0):

For a function using "known" functions

$$n(1-|\text{sgn}(\sigma_0(n)-2)|).$$

$\text{sgn}$ is the sign function

$\sigma_0$ is the number of divisors function